How to get the class type of an unnamed struct in a typedef inside the unnamed class?
This is a theoritcal question whether it is possible to get the type of the unnamed struct inside its definition.


int main() {
   struct {
         using ThisType = ???? //what do i put here?
    } _; // the instance
}

I tried to extract the class from a member finction pointer but it didnt work
template<typename>
struct get_class;

template<typename Class>
struct get_class<void(Class::*)()>{using type = Class;};

int main(){
struct {
    void getThis(){}
    using ThisType = typename get_class<decltype(getThis)>::type; // error cant know which function to call to determine 
    // i tried to static_cast but I need to know the class type still.
} _;
}

Is it even possible?

Based on the function name, I would expect an implementation like auto& getThis(){ return *this; } which might be more amenable to your goal.

but i need the* this* type in a typedef inside the struct itself. I could esily get the type of the struct after it is declared using  decltype(_) and getThis is like an internal function whose sole pupose is to get a member function pointer

Not sure if this works, but can you use the decltype of the function return of a function returning auto as the right hand side to typedef? If so just have a private function you never actually call but use as part of the typedef.

@SoronelHaetir error cant call member function without an object

@PeteBecker I know i can but I am asking whether it is possible. It is a pretty useless question But I am just wondering.

Sometimes it's better not to play. Just give it a name.

An interesting question, but I don't see anything that would make it possible without static reflection in C++2̵6̵ 2̵9̵ 3̵2̵ 35 maybe?

@Yksisarvinen I remember a proposal that allowed auto inside member declarations so you could get the ThisType like this struct {auto _this = this;using ThisType = decltype(_this);};

I wrote a library to be able to do this in a macro without naming the current type: https://godbolt.org/z/ja77Kzz9q. It works in this context too.
Here's a stripped down version with just the parts you need:
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
template<typename Tag>
struct retrieve_type {
    constexpr friend auto friend_function(retrieve_type<Tag>);
    constexpr auto member_function() {
        return friend_function(*this);
    }
};

template<typename Tag, typename Stored>
struct store_type {
    constexpr friend auto friend_function(retrieve_type<Tag>) {
        return std::type_identity<Stored>{};
    }
};
}

int main() {
    struct {
    private:
        struct tag_type;
        auto storer() -> decltype(detail::store_type<tag_type, decltype(this)>{});
    public:
        using ThisType = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(detail::retrieve_type<tag_type>{}.member_function())::type>;
    } _; // the instance
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(_)::ThisType, decltype(_)>);
}

This uses template metaprogramming to store the type of this available in the scope of the trailing return type and then retrieves it later.

nice work! although pretty useless but very interesting answer and techniques used! 1+ bonus for sizeof(_) == 1

can i ask why you needed this?

@user24551355 Some macros are used inside a class to defined members, so instead of #define DEFINE_MEMBER_FUNCTIONS(class_name) public: void f(class_name& other) { ... }, where you need to write the name of the current class (and possibly get it wrong or have double the diffs if you change the name), it could automatically be gotten like #define DEFINE_MEMBER_FUNCTIONS SELF_MACRO_DEFINE_SELF(self, private); public: void f(self& other) { ... }

This seems to work for both gcc and clang, at the cost of additional member in anonymous struct:
#include <type_traits>

template <class> struct get_class {};
template <class T>
struct get_class<T*(*)()> {
    using type = T;
};

int main() {
    struct {
        auto (*hack)() -> decltype(this);
        using ThisType = get_class<decltype(hack)>::type;
    } _; // the instance
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(_), decltype(_)::ThisType>);
}


oh nice no warnings doez this work on MSVC though? also there is no members so the sizeof struct is still 1 hack is a function

nope, hack is a function pointer here, so sizeof is 8 on my machine

does it work on MSVC? also yea i am wrong i thought i saw curly brackets at the end of the member declaration

https://godbolt.org/z/ffax97seb - it does

This seems to do the trick (using a helper function f):
Looks like you were close ;)
template <typename fn_t>
struct deduce_class_t
{
};

template <typename retval_t, typename class_t, typename... args_t>
struct deduce_class_t <retval_t(class_t::*)(args_t...)>
{
    using type_t = class_t;
};

struct
{
    void f();
    using type_t = typename deduce_class_t<decltype(&f)>::type_t;

} _;


i get this error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '& and this is the exact code i tried look at my post

Yup, it's non-standard C++. gcc only allows it with -fpermissive

@Yksisarvinen Well that sucks this would have been great to scare anyones working with me.

Me bad, I forgot to check multiple compilers

But then again... that it fails makes sense. It is kind of a jailbraik isn't it. ;)
